# How to stop Visual Studio 2019 from saving the whole solution when errors arise while debugging?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

So I'm now using Visual Studio 2019 in C# .Net Framework.

I have been programming in Visual Basic 6.0, and when I pressed `F5` the IDE run and if there were errors while debugging if I pressed the `X` to close the Vb6.0 IDE. a message box prompted saying if I wanted to save the changes since there were errors while debugging I pressed no.

Now in Visual Studio 2019 using C#, that doesn't happen. If I press `F5` and an error occurs while debugging, it autosaves the solution with its error. How can I stop it from saving with the error in it?

Comment: When you press F5, things happen. First, all your changed source files are save. Then that newly saved code is compiled. Then your program starts up under the control of the debugger. If you want, set up Git on your machine, integrate it with Visual Studio, and do a commit every time you are happy with your code. Now you have a complete history of all your changes

Comment: So there is no option to compile it without saving?

Comment: No, there isn't. The suggestion from @Flydog57 is your best option. Set up Git and commit your code frequently. Each commit is a snapshot of your code at the time you make the commit, and you can easily roll back to any commit. You will find this very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't debug code that hasn't been saved with Visual Studio.  If you want to see the process it goes through, do this:

- Open Tools -> Options
- Click "Projects and Solutions", then click "Build and Run"
- Change "MSBuild project build output verbosity" to "Normal" (or, if you want to see a lot of stuff, "Detailed" or "Diagnostic"
- Rebuild your project

You'll see VS invoking the compiler and passing the paths to each of your file (and to all of your references) to the compiler.  It needs to save and to compile and then execute your code.

The VS debugger is a full Windows debugger.  Open Windows Explorer, double-click your EXE.  Now open VS, in the Debug menu, choose "Attach to process" and choose your running EXE.  You are debugging it (you can attach to any process you have rights to, but attaching to a debug build where symbols are handy give you the best experience).

BASIC and pre-.NET VB started their lives as interpreted languages.  A pre-processor would take your source and convert it to *tokens*.  Then an interpreter would *interpret* those tokens as it ran your programs.  Though the last few versions of traditional VB could compile your code to an EXE, that interpreter was still there.

In particular, the debugger used it.  When you ran the VB6 (and earlier) debugger, the debugger didn't debug your program, it debugged your source - injecting itself into the interpreter, not attaching itself to the EXE.  That's why the behavior you are asking about worked.

As I mentioned, getting a Source Code Control system set up (which is always a good idea) will help you get close to what you want.  Git's probably the easiest to set up.  Visual Studio Team Foundation Services (or whatever it is called this month) is also a possibility.